# Почему пустой результат для запроса select c функцией substr?

Tags: mysql

Есть база в ней есть текстовое поле `preview_type`.

Хочу отобрать все записи у которых 5 символ = 1,

выполняю запрос:

```
select * from f_text_page where substr(`preview_type`,4,1)
```

пустой результат.
Может не так надо писать запрос?

Comment: substr вообще то php функция. string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
Возвращает подстроку строки string, начинающейся с start символа по счету и длиной length символов.

Comment: так если 5й символ вы получили, а на 1 то кто его проверять будет ?  И в mysql substr нумерует символы с 1, так что может все таки `substr(preview_type,5,1)='1'` ?

Comment: @axmed2004 А причем тут php ? функция substr имеется практически во всех языках и во всех базах данных и MySQL не исключение, в нем то же есть функция substr https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй вот так

```
select * from f_text_page where preview_type like '____1%'
```

Comment: Да, так помогло, спасибо.